# Gmail api authentacation not working with javascript

Tags: javascript, python, oauth, gmail-api

I am following [this](https://www.sitepoint.com/mastering-your-inbox-with-gmail-javascript-api/) tutorial. I git cloned the repository then added my credentials. I then used `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8888`
 to create my server. I get a screen that says 'Gmail API demo
' and nothing else :(. 
thanks in advance!
-Zoe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I finally figured it out. For anyone else with this issue, what you need to do is follow [this](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/js) tutorial to authenticate. then you can proceed with the rest.